# flutter freezed : equals type of object is not same

Tags: flutter, unit-testing, freezed

I am using freezed to make object from json :

```
@freezed
class UserMessagesResponseModel with _$UserMessagesResponseModel {
  const factory UserMessagesResponseModel({
    final Data? data,
  }) = _UserMessagesResponseModel;

  factory UserMessagesResponseModel.fromJson(final Map<String, dynamic> json) =>
      _$UserMessagesResponseModelFromJson(json);
}

@freezed
class Data with _$Data {
  const factory Data({
    final Messages? messages,
  }) = _Data;

  factory Data.fromJson(final Map<String, dynamic> json) =>
      _$DataFromJson(json);
}...
```

Now I am trying to make a test and chack type of created object:

```
test('should return a valid model', () async {
  final jsonMap =
      json.decode(fixture('message.json')) as Map<String, dynamic>;

  final result = UserMessagesResponseModel.fromJson(
    jsonMap,
  );
    
  expect(result, equals(UserMessagesResponseModel));
});
```

why I got error:

```
Expected: Type:<UserMessagesResponseModel>
  Actual: _$_UserMessagesResponseModel:<UserMessagesResponseModel...
```

Freezed Not make same type ? How can I check type ?

I also used:

```
expect(result, isA<UserMessagesResponseModel>);
```

but I got this:

```
Expected: <Closure: () => TypeMatcher<UserMessagesResponseModel> from Function 'isA': static.>
  Actual: _$_UserMessagesResponseModel:<UserMessagesResponseModel
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The first example

```
expect(result, equals(UserMessagesResponseModel));
```

doesn't work because result is an instance and `UserMessagesResponseModel` is a type, you should use `isA`.

**But on the second example I use `isA` and it still doesn't work!**

You missed the `()` after `isA`, I believe that is why it does't work.

from this:

```
expect(result, isA<UserMessagesResponseModel>);
```

to this:

```
expect(result, isA<UserMessagesResponseModel>());
```

Comment: Ops, yes It was my mistake to add (). Thanks .